# time based workflow rule

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

I'm using a free survey tool (Timba) and trying to create a time based workflow rule to accomplish the following:

send survey 1 day after a specific date is set on the account (survey fires from the contact on the account).

send another email 48 hours later if no response is received from the first survey that is sent out.

I can easily setup the 1 survey email time based workflow, but I cannot figure out how to send the 2nd email if no response is received.  And, the 2nd survey should only go out once. If there is no reply after that, then we do not want to sent out any further survey reminders.

Thanks for any thoughts on how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to have a field on the account that a response was received.  Assuming you had this populated once the response is received, then you could just create another Time Based WFR to go out 72 hours after your specific date (the original 24 + the next 48) IF the field indicating they have responded is null.

If they have responded, that field will not be sent out as the field will not be null.  It will only fire once as it will only fire 72 hours after your date.  It will fire again if you reset your date field but that goes without saying.

Hope that helps.